# ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'novalidate(ngSubmit)' is not a valid attribute name

Tags: html, angular

thanks for your help.

The console throws me the next error.

ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'novalidate(ngSubmit)' is not a valid attribute name.

I´m using Angular for this website.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkan3.png)

It´s the problem the novalidate() directive?

I do not know what to do, thanks for your time.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Order } from 'src/Model/order.model';
import { OrderRepository } from 'src/Model/order.repository';


@Component({
  templateUrl: './chech-out.component.html',
  //styleUrls: ['./chech-out.component.css']

})
export class ChechOutComponent implements OnInit {

  orderSent:boolean=false;
  submitted:boolean=false;


  constructor(public repository: OrderRepository,
              public order: Order)
  {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  submitOrder(form: NgForm)
  {
    this.submitted=true;
    if(form.valid)
    {
      this.repository.saveOrder(this.order)
      .subscribe(order =>{
        this.order.clear();
        this.orderSent=true;
        this.submitted=false;
      })
    }
  }

}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Order } from 'src/Model/order.model';
import { OrderRepository } from 'src/Model/order.repository';


@Component({
  templateUrl: './chech-out.component.html',
  //styleUrls: ['./chech-out.component.css']

})
export class ChechOutComponent implements OnInit {

  orderSent:boolean=false;
  submitted:boolean=false;


  constructor(public repository: OrderRepository,
              public order: Order)
  {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  submitOrder(form: NgForm)
  {
    this.submitted=true;
    if(form.valid)
    {
      this.repository.saveOrder(this.order)
      .subscribe(order =>{
        this.order.clear();
        this.orderSent=true;
        this.submitted=false;
      })
    }
  }

}
```

```css
input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid
{
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

input.ng-dirty.ng-valid
{
  border: 2px solid #6bc502;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col bg-dark text-white">
      <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/store">
        Online Store
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="orderSent" class="m-2 text-center">
  <h2>Thanks!</h2>
  <p > Thank you for your order </p>
  <p>Well send your order as soon as possible</p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/store">
    Return to Store
  </button>
</div>

<!--FORM-->
<form *ngIf="!orderSent" #form="ngForm" novalidate(ngSubmit)="submitOrder(form)" class="m-2">
<!--Name-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" #name="ngModel" name="name"
  [(ngModel)]="order.name" required/>
  <span *ngIf="submitted && name.invalid"
  class="text-danger">
    Please enter your name
  </span>
</div>
<!--Address-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Address</label>
  <input class="form-control" #address="ngModel" name="address"
  [(ngModel)]="order.address" required/>
  <span *ngIf="submitted && address.invalid"
  class="text-danger">
    Please enter your Address
  </span>
</div>
<!--City-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label>City</label>
  <input class="form-control" #city="ngModel" name="city"
  [(ngModel)]="order.city" required/>
  <span *ngIf="submitted && city.invalid"
  class="text-danger">
    Please enter your City
  </span>
</div>
<!--State-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label>State</label>
  <input class="form-control" #state="ngModel" name="state"
  [(ngModel)]="order.state" required/>
  <span *ngIf="submitted && state.invalid" class="text-danger">
    Please enter your State
  </span>
</div>
<!--Zip-->
<div class="form-group">
<label>ZIP Postal Code</label>
<input class="form-control" #zip="ngModel" name="zip"
[(ngModel)]="order.zip" required/>
<span *ngIf="submitted && zip.invalid" class="text-danger">
  Please enter your Zip Code
</span>
</div>
<!--Country-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Country</label>
  <input class="form-control" #country="ngModel" name="country"
  [(ngModel)]="order.country" required/>
  <span *ngIf="submitted && country.invalid" class="text-danger">
    Please enter your Country
  </span>
  </div>


  <!--Complete Order-->
<div class="text-center">

  <!--Button Back-->
<button class]="btn btn primary m-1" routerLink="/cart">
  Back
</button>
<!--Button Back-->

  <button class="btn- btn-primary m-1" type="submit">
    Complete Order
  </button>
</div>
<!--Complete Order-->

</form>






<!--FORM-->
```

```css
input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid
{
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

input.ng-dirty.ng-valid
{
  border: 2px solid #6bc502;
}
```

```html
And here is my code.

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col bg-dark text-white">
      <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/store">
        Online Store
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="orderSent" class="m-2 text-center">
  <h2>Thanks!</h2>
  <p > Thank you for your order </p>
  <p>Well send your order as soon as possible</p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/store">
    Return to Store
  </button>
</div>

<!--FORM-->
<form *ngIf="!orderSent" #form="ngForm" novalidate(ngSubmit)="submitOrder(form)" class="m-2">
<!--Name-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" #name="ngModel" name="name"
  [(ngModel)]="order.name" required/>
  <span *ngIf="submitted && name.invalid"
  class="text-danger">
    Please enter your name
  </span>
</div>
<!--Address-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Address</label>
  <input class="form-control" #address="ngModel" name="address"
  [(ngModel)]="order.address" required/>
  <span *ngIf="submitted && address.invalid"
  class="text-danger">
    Please enter your Address
  </span>
</div>
<!--City-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label>City</label>
  <input class="form-control" #city="ngModel" name="city"
  [(ngModel)]="order.city" required/>
  <span *ngIf="submitted && city.invalid"
  class="text-danger">
    Please enter your City
  </span>
</div>
<!--State-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label>State</label>
  <input class="form-control" #state="ngModel" name="state"
  [(ngModel)]="order.state" required/>
  <span *ngIf="submitted && state.invalid" class="text-danger">
    Please enter your State
  </span>
</div>
<!--Zip-->
<div class="form-group">
<label>ZIP Postal Code</label>
<input class="form-control" #zip="ngModel" name="zip"
[(ngModel)]="order.zip" required/>
<span *ngIf="submitted && zip.invalid" class="text-danger">
  Please enter your Zip Code
</span>
</div>
<!--Country-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Country</label>
  <input class="form-control" #country="ngModel" name="country"
  [(ngModel)]="order.country" required/>
  <span *ngIf="submitted && country.invalid" class="text-danger">
    Please enter your Country
  </span>
  </div>


  <!--Complete Order-->
<div class="text-center">

  <!--Button Back-->
<button class]="btn btn primary m-1" routerLink="/cart">
  Back
</button>
<!--Button Back-->

  <button class="btn- btn-primary m-1" type="submit">
    Complete Order
  </button>
</div>
<!--Complete Order-->

</form>
<!--FORM-->
```

Comment: try to add space between novalidate and (ngSubmit)

Comment: Thanks, i follow your advice

<form *ngIf="!orderSent" #form="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submitOrder(form)" class="m-2">

But the problem persists

Comment: Not really. I put the space between novalidate and (ngSubmit) as you say

Comment: but now the error should be different - you have a closing bracket ( ] ) after class word for back button

Comment: Thank you I delete the closing bracket and now it´s working fine

Answer (score 1):

I had this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '3' is not a valid attribute name.

And it turned out that I accidentally typed '3' at the bottom of the input field object. I just needed to be deleted.